# AJAX - Javascript is breaking whenever the AJAX script is called

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I hired a developer to help with some work, he was mostly PHP focused and attempted this javascript. The following AJAX script breaks the page whenever it reloads the HTML into the DOM. It called a function via Codenigniter to reload the `view` within the page. Once this happens, all of the javascript no longer works.

I can't seem to find a solution that helps solve this issue. Please help.

*Note: Ideally I would of rather the code only loaded the data and not refresh the HTML, but for now this will need to do as I am up against a timeline.*

**The code:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Ajax Form Submit
    $('body').on('click', '.submitForm', function () {

        var formid = $(this).parents('form').attr('id');
        var validationResult = $('#' + formid).validationEngine('validate');
        if (!validationResult) {
            return false;
        }
        var url = $('#' + formid).attr('action');
        var formdata = $('#' + formid).serialize();
        if ($('#' + formid).find('.submitForm').hasClass('loading')) {
            $(this).hide();
            $('#' + formid).find('.loader').show();
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            url: url,
            data: formdata,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                if ($('#' + formid).find('.submitForm').hasClass('loading')) {
                    $('#' + formid).find('.submitForm').css('display', 'inline');
                    $('#' + formid).find('.loader').hide();
                }

                if (data.type == 'add') {
                    if (data.html) {
                        var newhtml = "<tr>" + data.html + "</tr>";
                        $('.tab-pane.active table').append(newhtml);
                    }
                    $('#' + formid).find('.message').html(data.msg).show();
                    $('#' + formid).trigger('reset');
                    setInterval(function () {
                        $('#' + formid).find('.message').hide();
                    }, 5000);
                } else {
                    if (data.error) {
                        $('#' + formid + ' .message').show().html(data.error);
                    } else {
                        $('#' + formid + ' .message').show().html(data.msg);
                        if (data.reload_loc) {
                            window.setTimeout(function () {
                                window.location.href = data.reload_loc;
                            }, 4 * 1000);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });


    // Generic Save Form Data
    $('body').on('click', '#saveFormdata', function () {
        var formid = $(this).parents('form').attr('id');
        var validationResult = $('#' + formid).validationEngine('validate');

        if (!validationResult) {
            return false;
        }

        $('#' + formid).submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: instead of `$('body')` try `$(document)`

Comment: Didn't work. I'm assuming you meant the two statements followed by `.on('click'`

Comment: I didn't read all your code. But please tell me: Are you trying to replace these element .submitForm and #saveFormdata?

Comment: The way he wrote it yes. Runs a PHP controller that loads the same view. Not my preferred approach but what in working with.

Comment: You cannot replace these elements ".submitForm" and "#saveFormdata" by the new one. If after loading ajax, you replace these elements, It won't work again.

Comment: Clearly. How should this be approached? I don't have any AJAX experience and am trying to fix another's mistakes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63469/discussion-between-user2853290-and-dvoutt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just do something like this:

```
function bindEvent()
{
    $('body').on('click', '.submitForm', function () { //Your code });
    $('body').on('click', '#saveFormdata', function () { //Your code});
}

function unblindEvent()
{
    $('body').off('click', '.submitForm'); //Something like this, please read Jquery.off 
    $('body').off('click', '#saveFormdata');
}
```

Before you replace these element, call unblindEvent(). And after you replace these elements call bindEvent().

Comment: Not exactly sure why I want to do these and how to make sure one is called and then the other. I'll send you a message.

Comment: Are you try this? If you cannot fix it. contact me, I will fix it for you.